# addTextChangedListener to save a new object

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, textwatcher

I've a listView with some textView and one editText. I would save a new object when user modifies value of editText. I implemented a TextWatcher but I can't able to retrieve a values of specific textView which referred to editText modified. Anybody help me?

**EDIT**

*TextWatcher for specific line of listView*

```
quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){ 
            if (Integer.parseInt(s.toString())!=0){


                HashMap<Products, Integer> into = new HashMap<Products, Integer>();

                Products pr = new Products();
                            //product contains value of textView 
                pr.set_id(Integer.parseInt(product.get("id")));
                pr.setNome(product.get("nome"));
                into.put(pr, Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                pArrayList.add(into);
                cart.setProdotti(pArrayList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code for adding the textWatcher?

Comment: In afterTextChanged() you want to get the value of different TextView's? Sorry but I don't really get your question...

Comment: I've a listView with a lot of products, and for every one of this I've a 3 TextView: name, price,description. Now I add an editText. When I modify this editText i would save an instance of a new object. My problem is retrieve values of textView into TextWatcher

Comment: You need to assign an unique id to every TextView, then in afterTextChanged() you can get the value of the textView's by calling findViewById() for each id.

Comment: Added some example code. Let me know if I misunderstood you Claudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/p1_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Product 1" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/p1_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="20" />


public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    ...
    String price = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.p1_price)).getText();
    ...
}
```

Comment: it's ok, but I would retrieve HashMap<String, String> passed to arrayadapter and use this in my TextWatcher because not all values into HashMap are used into view

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's little bit overkill but you can use in each line setTag() method for View for TextView and EditText so the both Views will be somehow connected by this key. Then you only need to call findViewByTag(). This operation is little bit expensive so make sure to call it only when user stops writting.

Comment: my listview contains a lot of products, this solution I think isn't the best